# Why is array destructuring not working in this case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I am trying to swap members of arr.
But I am getting [0, 0] as output.
I am expecting [1, 0].

```js
const arr = [0, 1];
[arr[1],arr[0]] = arr;
console.log(arr)
```

But while doing this, it outputs
[1, 0] which I think I understand.

```js
const arr = [0, 1];
[arr[1],arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr[1]];
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: The destructuring assignment is modifying the array. `arr[1]` becomes `0`, and then so does `arr[0]`

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code you posted is weird and doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Utshav - I had the array indexes backward in my answer, which may have made it hard to understand. I've fixed them.

Answer (score 6):

Your first example is both **modifying** the array `arr` points to **and** getting its values from that same array, as though you did this:

```
const arr = [0, 1];
// Here, `arr` is `[0, 1]`
arr[1] = arr[0];      // <=== Changes `arr[1]`...
// Now, `arr` is `[0, 0]`
arr[0] = arr[1];      // <=== ...so the new value of `arr[1]` is used here.
// Still `[0, 0]`
```

Your destructuring is doing the same thing: Using `arr[1]` **after** it's been changed by the destructuring assignment.

Your second example is modifying the array `arr` points to, but only after getting the old values from the array into a **new** array:

```
const arr = [0, 1];
const newArray = [arr[0], arr[1]];
// Here, `arr` is `[0, 1]`, `newArray` is `[0, 1]`
arr[1] = newArray[0]; // <=== Changes `arr[1]`...
// Here, `arr` is `[0, 0]`, `newArray` is still `[0, 1]`
arr[0] = newArray[1]; // <=== ...but that doesn't affect `newArray[1]`, so this works.
// Here, `arr` is `[1, 0]`, `newArray` is still `[0, 1]`
```

That works, because even though `arr[1]` was changed by the destructuring assignment, the new value for `arr[0]` isn't coming from `arr[1]`, it's coming from `newArray[1]`.